# Why are Dispersion Interactions Stronger in Molecules with Bigger Molecular Mass?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

Usually there are two explanations:

1. When dipoles are induced due to movement of electrons in the molecule, they are bigger in molecules with more mass since they have/include more atoms (has sense to me)
2. Bigger molecules have bigger contact or "surface area"

What does "surface area" between molecules have to do with how strong dipoles are induced?

Comment: Possibly repeating some other Q/A like this one: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/104537/81. certainly much overlap if not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. Here is a quote from the answer: "More surface, more opportunity for the fluctuations to interact with other molecules." What does that mean? What I would say regarding how strong dispersion forces are is that the bigger dipole the stronger the interaction. Dipoles are induced by fluctuations. Dipole will be bigger if more charges are separated and if they are separed by greater distance so that centers of positive and negative charge are separated by greater distance. What does that have to do with the surface area?

Comment: The fluctuations are random. Their individual *strength* does not change with surface area. But the *number* of random fluctuations does change with surface area: more area, more opportunity for fluctuations. Hence the overall sum of the forces between two molecules varies but not the *individual* scale of the dipoles.

Comment: Fluctutations do cause shift of centers of positive and negative charge in a molecule. If molecules are non polar this creates dipole. What does number of fluctuations have to do with how strong dipoles are created?

Comment: The fluctuations are driven by quantum uncertainty in the position of electron clouds and so appear randomly. The strength of an individual random varying dipole has nothing to do with the size of the molecule. But the number that can occur depends on the number of electrons. The electron clouds capable of interacting with another molecule depends on the surface area.

Comment: It didn't really answer my question what does number of fluctuations have to do with how strong dipoles are created in a molecule? Number is bigger in bigger molecules, yes. What ultimately determines the strength of dispersion forces between molecules is how strong dipoles are able to be created in a molecule, not number of fluctuations itself.

Comment: Precisely wrong. The *size* of the fluctuating dipoles does not vary (they are just probabilistic quantum fluctuations that don't relate to surface area at al). Therefore, the overall force between molecules (all the dipoles in each molecule interacting) depends on the *number* not the strength of the dipoles (which doesn't vary).

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't agree. There aren't dipoles in a molecule there is only one dipole. If centers of positive and negative charge aren't at the same point in space dipole is created and dipole moment of a molecule becomes different from zero. Fluctuations of electrons create dipoles in non polar molecules. How can there be more than one dipole on level of a molecule? We can maybe talk about dipoles of particular groups within a molecule if within specific group (which is non polar) there is separation of centers of positive and negative charge and that can justify what you said.

Comment: Also, how can strength of dipoles not vary if they are created by random motion of electrons? How can random motion create unchanging dipole?

Comment: You are not getting the key distinction between dispersion forces and other intermolecular forces driven by *permanent* dipole interactions. these are totally different forces and the interactions from permanent dipoles are usually far stronger. But not in non-polar molecules where the dominant interactions are dispersion forces.

Comment: This is the same answer someone already posted here, but thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me what the important distinction is?